# Java SQL Insert rows with auto-increment id

Tags: java, sql, insert

I'm trying to insert into a database with the following columns, however I'm getting the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Id) Values ('Gonzalo','Higuain','09 7 2018','Argentina',12.0,'Attacker','Right',' at line 1

1. id, int auto-increment
2. FirstName, Text
3. LastName, Text
4. DateOfBirth, Text
5. Nationality, Text
6. Height, Float
7. Position, Text
8. StrongFoot, Text
9. TeamId, Int

   ```
       DatabaseConnection DatabaseConnect= new DatabaseConnection();     
       DatabaseConnect.getConnection();                                  
       Statement mystatement = DatabaseConnect.myConn.createStatement();
       String club = ("Insert into players ( FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Nationality, Height, Position, StrongFoot, Team Id) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
       PreparedStatement input = DatabaseConnect.myConn.prepareStatement(club);
       input.setString(1, fName);
       input.setString(2, lName);
       input.setString(3, formattedDate);
       input.setString(4, nationality);
       input.setDouble(5, height);
       input.setString(6, position);
       input.setString(7, foot);
       input.setInt(8, teamId);
       input.executeUpdate();
   ```

Comment: You never used `mystatement`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String club = ("Insert into players ( FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Nationality, Height, Position, StrongFoot, Team Id) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

I think `Team Id` above should be `TeamId`. You have a space in there. Here's what it should be:

```
String club = ("Insert into players ( FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Nationality, Height, Position, StrongFoot, TeamId) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```